# Dependency injection without IOC - How to avoid wrong usage in production code?

Tags: c#

NOTE: Question at the bottom.

I am working on a legacy project (with 0 unit test coverage) and it is impossible to refactor the whole system to use IOC. As of now, we are trying to inject mock/fake object by public setter (I know this is bad).

This is one of the example we try to inject mock to some singletons

```
public class SingletonContainer
{
    private static IClock clock = new RealClock();   

    private static SingletonContainer container;
    public static SingletonContainer Instance
    {
        /* some singleton implementation*/
    }

    public IClock Clock { get; set;}
 }

// IClock has 2 implementations : RealClock and ManualClock
public interface IClock
{
    DateTime Now();   // In real clock will only return DateTime.Now
                      // In Manual clock will always return the time from SetTime()
    void SetTime(DateTime newTime);  // In real clock will threw exception.
}
```

The above design did provide me full control on the time in unit test.
But, we do not want the developer accidentally calling SetTime() in non-testing code.

Jon Skeet suggest that it can be done by

```
 if (assembly.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("nunit.framework"))
```

But that idea got shut down during design review. The tech lead want to use class design to solve this problem instead.

Question: 
How to hide ManualClock or hide SetTime() method without implementing nasty hack ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just get rid of the IClock.SetTime declaration and have the method defined only on the ManualClock class. That is if you have access to ManualClass instance from your tests, which you probably have.

Having the SetTime on the IClock looks like a design smell to me.
[Specifically I think it violates LSP (Liskov substitution principle)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170925/does-liskov-substitution-principle-also-apply-to-classes-implementing-an-interfa)

Comment: Oh, Right ... you remind me about my original design. The realclock should never has the setTime method that did nothing but throw exception in the first place. IClock should only be a wrapper class to wrap up method like Now or Today from datatime. Only ManualClock (that only exist in nunit test project) should have the SetTime method instead. Looks like it's a cleaner way to solve the problem